# Phonegap AppCache disable

Tags: cordova, angularjs

I would like to completely disable appcache for my phonegap application.
It doesn't allow me to use dynamic $http resources.

I've added `"manifest="cache.manifest"` to my `<html>` tag and in the **cache.manifest** file I put

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/css/app.css
```

to just cache my css file and nothing more.

Can I disable appcache somehow ?
There might be a problem with mime-type maybe?